# Converting PDF to Word in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, itext, apache-poi, converters

I want to convert my pdf file to word , i've search & found itext for reading pdf and apache poi for convert word, i have a problem how to use it :D hehe,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView browsefile, filename;
ImageView gambar;
int RequestFile = 2;
Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    browsefile = findViewById(R.id.browsefile);
    filename = findViewById(R.id.filename);
    gambar = findViewById(R.id.gambarfile);
    mContext = MainActivity.this;

    browsefile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startOptionBrowseFile();
        }
    });


}

private void startOptionBrowseFile() {
    Intent openFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    openFileIntent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(openFileIntent, RequestFile);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RequestFile && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        Uri selectedFile = data.getData();

        
        File path = new File(selectedFile.getPath());
        filename.setText(selectedFile.getPath());

        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
        String pdf = String.valueOf(path);
        PdfReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
```

// Read the PDF page by page

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            TextExtractionStrategy strategy = null;
            try {
                strategy = parser.processContent(i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Extract the text
            String text=strategy.getResultantText();
            // Create a new paragraph in the word document, adding the extracted text
            XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();
            XWPFRun run = p.createRun();
            run.setText(text);
            // Adding a page break
            run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
        }
```

// Write the word document

```
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream("myfile.docx");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            doc.write(out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

// Close all open files

```
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        reader.close();

    }
}


}
```

And this is the error

[image: Error Image]

Can anyone help me?I am grateful if anyone can solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

The interface `Paragraph`is not found in classpath. This failure happend in older POI versions because the WL and SL interfaces were inside `scratchpad`, which is not included in `poi` jar.

### POI older than V4.1.2

When you are using an older version than 4.1.2 you must also add the `poi-scrachpad` library as dependency to your classpath / build.gradle

See
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad

### Switch to POI V4.1.2

As you can see at
https://github.com/apache/poi/commit/f2dba42227abb4edf0ba0313972762974585693f
the WP and SL interfaces were moved by this commit on 28 May 2015 for release 4.1.2

So if you are using 4.1.2 you simple need just a dedicated POI library jar in classpath/build.gradle and the Paragraph interface must be found (see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi)

If this is still a problem, ensure you have added the POI library as an `implementation` dependency and not accidently only for `test`.

`build.gradle` example:

```
dependencies {
   // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml
   compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.1.2'
}
```

Comment: Hi @de-jcup can you plz provide a working example if not possible library links i have been trying to make it work for weeks in android studio but i cant get it to work either there duplicate error or exception or no class found or sometimes its ok but class not found in runtime not matter what i do i just cant get it to work i use android studio : arctic fox
i simple want to convert ms office files to pdf

Comment: The question was about conversion from PDF to MS Word. Of course it should work in the other direction as well but it is still different. I would suggest to create a new question about this. But short: You should try to create just a simple gradle java project and add the newest dependencies (Apache PDF box (or itext) + POI OOXML) and create a simple "normal" application reading the PDF + write by POI. See XSSF examples at http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/examples.html  and http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/use-case.html . After POC works adopt to your Android project.

Comment: yes i have already created a question also i can find some excel examples and Word and PowerPoint examples are hard to find especially for android studio that's why i was looking to convert all i want to do is view it
This is link to my question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69113420/ms-office-files-to-pdf-in-java-using-apache-poi

Comment: I have just answered in your linked question - please read.